# How to combine the values of the same field from several rows into one string in a one-to-many select?

Tags: sql, sybase

Imagine the following two tables:

```
create table MainTable (
  MainId integer not null, -- This is the index
  Data varchar(100) not null
)

create table OtherTable (
  MainId integer not null,    -- MainId, Name combined are the index.
  Name varchar(100) not null,
  Status tinyint not null
)
```

Now I want to select all the rows from `MainTable`, while combining all the rows that match each `MainId` from `OtherTable` into a single field in the result set.

Imagine the data:

```
MainTable:
1, 'Hi'
2, 'What'

OtherTable:
1, 'Fish', 1
1, 'Horse', 0
2, 'Fish', 0
```

I want a result set like this:

```
MainId, Data,   Others
1,      'Hi',   'Fish=1,Horse=0'
2,      'What', 'Fish=0'
```

What is the most elegant way to do this?

(Don't worry about the comma being in front or at the end of the resulting string.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no really elegant way to do this in Sybase.  Here is one method, though:

```
select 
  mt.MainId, 
  mt.Data,
  Others = stuff((
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then ','+Name+'='+cast(status as varchar(255)) else '' end) +
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then ','+Name+'='+cast(status as varchar(255)) else '' end) +
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then ','+Name+'='+cast(status as varchar(255)) else '' end)
           ), 1, 1, '')
from MainTable mt 
  left outer join
    (select 
       ot.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by MainId order by status desc) as seqnum
     from OtherTable ot
    ) ot
    on mt.MainId = ot.MainId
group by
  mt.MainId, md.Data
```

That is, it enumerates the values in the second table.  It then does conditional aggregation to get each value, using the `stuff()` function to handle the extra comma.  The above works for the first three values.  If you want more, then you need to add more clauses.

Comment: As interesting as your answer is; I cannot get `row_number() over (partition by ...)` to work, because Sybase keeps complaining about a syntax error near 'over'.

Comment: @svip . . . Not all versions of Sybase support the window functions.  I guess you are using an older version.  How many different values does `status` take on?

Comment: Well, in my actual tables (which are more detailed than those in the example), `Status` has 3 values: 0, 1 and 2.  If 2, I render '1', otherwise '0' using a `case when else end` clause.  That thing works.  In my implementation I order by `Name`.

Comment: Well, if it does not work in 12.x, then I must pass on the functionality, I'm afraid.  Because a lot of our clients still run 12.x.  I am thinking of using a help table and a cursor instead.

Comment: Is there a finite list of names in the "Other" table?  You can do the same idea, name by name.

Comment: Technically, yes, but it is - or at least should be - unknown by the database/sql, and only known by the application side.  I'd rather not have to update numerous stored procedures, whenever we add a new element (and unfortunately, it is a seldom procedure we add new ones; so this will never be routine).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is how I implemented it in Sybase 13.x.  This code has the advantage of not being limited to a number of `Name`s.

```
create proc
as
  declare
    @MainId int,
    @Name   varchar(100),
    @Status tinyint

  create table #OtherTable (
    MainId     int          not null,
    CombStatus varchar(250) not null
  )

  declare OtherCursor cursor for
    select
        MainId, Name, Status
      from
        Others

  open OtherCursor
    fetch OtherCursor into @MainId, @Name, @Status
    while (@@sqlstatus = 0) begin -- run until there are no more
      if exists (select 1 from #OtherTable where MainId = @MainId) begin
        update #OtherTable
          set CombStatus = CombStatus + ','+@Name+'='+convert(varchar, Status)
          where
            MainId = @MainId
      end else begin
        insert into #OtherTable (MainId, CombStatus)
          select
            MainId = @MainId,
            CombStatus = @Name+'='+convert(varchar, Status)
      end

      fetch OtherCursor into @MainId, @Name, @Status
    end
  close OtherCursor

  select
      mt.MainId,
      mt.Data,
      ot.CombStatus
    from
      MainTable mt
        left join #OtherTable ot
          on mt.MainId = ot.MainId
```

But it does have the disadvantage of using a cursor and a working table, which can - at least with a lot of data - make the whole process slow.